# Apache TomEEでMySQLのDataSourceが設定できない

Tags: java-ee

「apache-tomee-7.0.3-plume」をインストールし、Eclipseと連携させて動かしています。
MySQLのDataSourceを設定して利用しようとしたのですが、どうしてもデフォルトのHSQLDBしか読み込まれません。
DataSourceの設定はTomEEのマニュアルを読んで以下のように記述しました。
MySQLの起動やtestデータベースの存在、設定内容などは問題ありません。

```
<Resource id="MySQLDB" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl    jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    UserName   root
    Password   mysql
</Resource>
```

マニュアルにはTomEEインストール・ディレクトリの「conf/tomee.xml」もしくはWebアプリケーションの「WEB-INF/conf/resources.xml」のいずれかに記述すると書かれており、両方試しました。
JDBC DriverはTomEEインストール・ディレクトリの「lib」およびWebアプリケーション下の「WEB-INF/lib」の両方に配置しています。
同様の問題に直面している[投稿](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231674/how-to-remove-hsqldb-datasource-in-tomee)を参考にしてEclipseのサーバーのLocationも変更しました。
しかし、どうしても設定したDataSourceを読み取ってくれず、以下の単純なコードの実行結果は「DB:HSQL Database Engine」と表示され、デフォルトのHSQLDBがDataSourceとして使われているようです。

```
@Resource(name="MySQLDB")
private DataSource ds;
・・・
System.out.println("DB:" + ds.getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
```

ログには「情報: Creating Resource(id=My DataSource)」と表示されており、設定したMySQLBのDataSourceは作成されていないようです。例外は発生していません。

インターネット上で情報を調べたのですが、行き詰っています。
どなたか何かわかるようでしたら情報をお願いします。

Comment: その後の調査で、言及した投稿にも書かれているようにEclipse上のサーバーが設定ファイルを正しく見れていないことが判明しました (Eclipseを使用せずにTomEEを起動してアプリケーションを配備したところ、問題なくMySQLのDataSourceが取得できたため)。サーバーのLocationの設定だけではダメなようですが、今のところEclipseの設定をどのようにすればよいのかは判明していません。とりあえず、conf/tomee.xmlファイルをEclipseの「workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf」ディレクトリにコピーすることで、Eclipse上でもうまく動きます。引き続き調査してみますが、何か情報があればよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

> JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

のように書いていますが、[公式ドキュメント](http://tomee.apache.org/admin/configuration/resources.html)では`=`を付けていますね。

```
<Resource id="MySQLDB" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl    = jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    UserName   = root
    Password   = mysql
</Resource>
```